# How to compare between each columns text value?

Tags: python, pandas, compare, isin

I want to compare with each columns in python.

for instance :

| no. | name | name_convert | contains |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | applepie | apple | True |
| 1 | applepie | strawberry | False |
| 2 | bananashake | banana | True |
| 3 | bananashake | banana | True |

I want to create `contains` columns. It defines result of comparison of each column (`name` with `name_convert`). applepie (in `name`) contains apple(in `name_convert`) string.

How can I create a new column that contains True if the `name_convert` is substring of `name`?

Here is my attempt:

```
data['contains'] = data['name'].isin(data['name_convert'])
```

Comment: add your code and let's see what you have done so far.

Comment: I add it. please read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `list comprehension` and `zip` function:

```
df['contains']=[i in j for i,j in zip(df['name_convert'],df['name'])]

: df
Out[10]: 
   no.         name name_convert  contains
0    0     applepie        apple      True
1    1     applepie   strawberry     False
2    2  bananashake       banana      True
3    3  bananashake       banana      True
```